# R: reshape() creating a different wide format

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe in long format grouped by "id", which goes from 1 to 135 and "date" which are dates from "2020-03-01" until "2022-01-09" (see below).

[image]

The thing is I am trying to put it in wide format so that I have 135 rows and 3 * 680 columns (number of variables:x,y,z) * (unique values of dates:680). The thing is when I type the following code:

```r
df.w <- reshape(df,
                timevar = "date",
                idvar = "id",
                direction = "wide")
```

I obtain a 135*4 matrix with a column with the ids (correct) but only 3 columns with the names of x.c(all the dates values), y.c(all the dates values) and z.c(all the dates values) and their values are NA.

I have tried three things:

1. Reordering the data frame according to date and reshaping it but I obtain the same result.
2. Changing the "date" variable type (date) to numeric (ordering from 1 to 680 the dates) and it still gives the same result.
3. I have done it with a self-created small data frame and I am obtaining the correct result (see below). However, I can't see the difference from what I am doing to the example below.

```r
id <- rep(1:5, each = 3)
date <- rep(1980:1982, 5)
x <- rep(1:5, each = 3)
y <- rep(5:1, each = 3)
z <- rep(7:11, each = 3)
df.trial <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,date,x,y,z))
df.trial$id <- as.factor(df.trial$id)
df.trial$date <- as.factor(df.trial$date)
df.w <- reshape(df.trial,
                timevar = "date",
                idvar = "id",
                direction = "wide")
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance. (I am trying to upload the data frame I have and the result but I can't figure how to do it)

The output of dput(head(df,n=100)) is:

```r
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 
    18328, 18329, 18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 
    18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 
    18346, 18347, 18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 
    18355, 18356, 18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18363, 
    18364, 18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 
    18373, 18374, 18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 18381, 
    18382, 18383, 18384, 18385, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 
    18391, 18392, 18393, 18394, 18395, 18396, 18397, 18398, 18399, 
    18400, 18401, 18402, 18403, 18404, 18405, 18406, 18407, 18408, 
    18409, 18410, 18411, 18412, 18413, 18414, 18415, 18416, 18417, 
    18418, 18419, 18420, 18421), class = "Date"), x = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), y = c(5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 5.94886178728404, 
    5.94886178728404, 5.970113496222, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 5.99135365719321, 
    9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 
    9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 
    9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 
    9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913, 9.10742411719913), z = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.168099383673284, 0, 0, 0.168099383673284, 0, 
    0, 0.168099383673284, 0.336198767346569, 0, 0, 0.168099383673284, 
    0.168099383673284, 0.168099383673284, 0.336198767346569, 
    0.336198767346569, 0, 0.504298151019853, 0.168099383673284, 
    1.34479506938628, 0.672397534693138, 0.672397534693138, 0.336198767346569, 
    0.336198767346569, 0.168099383673284, 0.168099383673284, 
    0.336198767346569, 0.672397534693138, 0, 0.672397534693138, 
    0, 0, 0.168099383673284, 0.336198767346569, 0.504298151019853, 
    0.168099383673284, 0.168099383673284, 0.336198767346569, 
    0, 0, 0.500721568388507, 0.166907189462836, 0.166907189462836, 
    0, 0.166907189462836, 0.166907189462836, 0, 0.166907189462836, 
    0.166907189462836, 0.667628757851343, 0.166907189462836, 
    0.333814378925671, 0, 0, 0.333814378925671, 0.166907189462836, 
    0.333814378925671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166907189462836, 0, 0.166907189462836, 
    0.166907189462836, 0, 0, 0, 0.333814378925671, 0.500721568388507, 
    0, 0.667628757851343, 0, 0, 0.166907189462836, 0, 0.166907189462836, 
    0.166907189462836, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.109800530548646, 
    0.109800530548646, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    id = structure(1L, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
    "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
    "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
    "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
    "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", 
    "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", 
    "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", 
    "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
    "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", 
    "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", 
    "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", 
    "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", 
    "133", "134", "135"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: can you do a dput(head(df,n=100))) and copy paste the output of the first 100 rows of the dataframe so we can work with it?

Comment: Updated with the put output. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Using your example with the first 100 rows works fine if `tibble` and `dplyr` **are not loaded**. So removing the extra attributes with `as.data.frame()` makes it work. The question is why doesn't it work with `tibble` and/or `dplyr` loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes no sense at all the requirement of not having dplyr and tibble loaded. Thank you again.

Comment: Poking around a bit more, I think I've narrowed it down the problem to `stats::reshape()` expecting a vector when subsetting (during the check for dublicate IDs, line 132 onwards) and `tibble`'s behaviour is only to do so with the drop argument. Basically, `stats::reshape()` isn't written to accomodate the changes `tibble` makes to subsetting behaviour for data frames and thus ends up thinking there are duplicates where there aren't.

Basically if you want to use `stats::reshape()` you have to make your data a "normal" data frame with `as.data.frame()` first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do get the desired output with [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = c(x, y, z), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("date", "variable"), values_from = "value") |>
  ungroup()

# Output:
# A tibble: 1 × 301
  id    `2020-03-01_x` `2020-03-01_y` `2020-03-01_z` `2020-03-02_x`
  <fct>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1                  0           5.95              0              0
# ℹ 296 more variables: `2020-03-02_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-02_z` <dbl>,
#   `2020-03-03_x` <dbl>, `2020-03-03_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-03_z` <dbl>,
#   `2020-03-04_x` <dbl>, `2020-03-04_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-04_z` <dbl>,
#   `2020-03-05_x` <dbl>, `2020-03-05_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-05_z` <dbl>,
#   `2020-03-06_x` <dbl>, `2020-03-06_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-06_z` <dbl>,
#   `2020-03-07_x` <dbl>, `2020-03-07_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-07_z` <dbl>,
#   `2020-03-08_x` <dbl>, `2020-03-08_y` <dbl>, `2020-03-08_z` <dbl>, …
```

Comment: I can't make it work with reshape just yet  currently having an aneurysm trying to figure it out. Is there a particular reason why you want to use reshape?

Comment: Not really, I was following an example. I have been using pivot_wider() and even if the result is not exactly the same it works. Thanks for the answers.